# Remote Desktop: Streaming audio on both computer

Tags: audio, remote-desktop

When I connect to my other computer using rdp, I have three choices: listen audio from my remote desktop, listen audio to my client computer, or don't listen to audio at all.

But I'd like the audio to keep on playing on the server computer and hear it at the same time. Because now if I want to listen to the audio of this computer on my computer, the other computer won't play while mine (the client) will hear it...

I don't know if it's clear enough, but thanks :)